# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to change the color of button but i get this message with any method (style,innerHtml,...)

> > error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

html:
`

```
        <div class="a-section backGround layer">
        </div>
        <div class="a-section layer">
            <div class="a-row dealDetailContainer">
                <div class="a-row a-spacing-mini">
                    <div class="a-row a-spacing-unspecified">
                        <span class="a-size-mini a-color-base hiddenCss">&nbsp;</span>
                        <span class="a-size-mini a-color-base badgeSkew"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="a-row stackToBottom">

                    <div class="a-row a-spacing-medium">

                        <span class="a-declarative">

                            <span class="a-button a-button-normal a-button-span12 a-button-primary fixedWidth210">
                                <span class="a-button-inner">
                                <button class="a-button-text a-text-center" type="button">
                                        Add to Cart
                                </button>

                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

js:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName=(".a-button-primary .a-button-text");
var i;
for(i=0 ; i <= button.length ; i++){
  button[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName=(`? You should be getting syntax errors in your console... Also `getElementsByClassName` takes the names of classes, not selectors (i.e., without the dot).

Comment: I TRIED IT WITHOUT dot  AND DIDNT WORK

Comment: Please turn off your caps lock. Writing in all caps is considered yelling in most online communities.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in @Heretic's comment, your syntax is incorrect. Another issue I found is that you are looping beyond the length of the returned elements. In your `for` loop, you are using `<=` instead of `<`. Because we're starting at `0`, `<=` will go too far and return `undefined` when the loop exceeds the actual element length.

Here is a basic example of what you're trying to do.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("my-button");
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">hello</button>
<button class="my-button">hello</button>
<button class="my-button">hello</button>
```